# Magento Daily Import

Tags: magento-1.9

What is the best way to keep around 10K to 15K products to be imported on daily bases to make any changes to attributes or pricing ? we did try using default Magento but its either goes

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

or

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Is there any other easy way of keeping the daily import?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are your indexers configured in admin?
It seems your store has lock file present due to core_url_rewrite reindexing or due to other reindexing process. You need to remove any lock files in var/ directory, make the following indexers set as 'Manual Update'

1. Product Price
2. Product Attribute
3. Core Url Rewrite
4. Product Flat Data
5. Category Products
6. Category Flat Data
7. catalog Search Index

And run the importer again. Once imported, from CLI run those indexers manually.
Well, that's a guess.

If you share, how your indexers are configured and how this importer works would be help to resolve this.

Comment: I already setup the indexer to manual all the time and after the import is perform , I did added the command to reindex all indexers.  I did created a simple shell script to point and use the default data profile import .